# MYSQL - INSERT INTO using WHERE condition of Table 1

Tags: mysql, insert, where-clause, insert-into

after reading all the "INSERT INTO" posts as well as the documentation, I am still unsure whether what I want is feasible or not.
I want to change the UPDATE below into an INSERT INTO, because I have many 100-thousands of them (speed issues):

```
   UPDATE city c 
   SET 
    c.g17h = '3196504', 
    c.g17q = '2593487', 
    c.g17k = '0', 
    c.g17w = '0', 
    c.g17s = '0' 
   WHERE
    p17t = 30 AND p17l = '30';
```

or

```
UPDATE city c 
SET 
 c.g1h = '0', 
 c.g1q = '0', 
 c.g1k = '0', 
 c.g1w = '0', 
 c.g1s = '0' 
WHERE
 p1t = 1 
 AND p1l = '1';
```

However, my best solutions do not work:

```
INSERT INTO city (g17h, g17q, g17k, g17w, g17s)  
SELECT 
 '3196504',
 '2593487', 
 '0', 
 '0', 
 '0' 
FROM valuestoretab 
WHERE 
 p17t = 30 
 AND p17l = '30';
```

This is of course because my WHERE condition can only be satisfied in the first table (city) but not in the second one which is just a table of values, whereas the city table is a data set where each id has particular values for p17t, p17l and so on.
For clarification:

```
The first table (city) looks like
cityid1, ownerid1, islandid1, p17t, p17l
cityid2, ownerid2, islandid2, p17t, p17l
```

with different values for each row for p17t and p17l.

So, my questions would be:
1. Is it at all possible to write a INSERT-Query with a WHERE condition for the table that is being inserted into?
2. If no, do I have to stick to my UPDATE or is there another (fast!) solution?

Thanks to the community!

litotes

Comment: What are those row names? Do you have any idea? This seems like an easy way to extend bug debugging by a bunch of time ("*aaah - I used `g17w` instead of `g17q`. Silly me!*").

Comment: These row names indicate 5 types of resources per city, e.g. q for quarry that are needed for 1-32 buildings that may be built on 1-17 places in each city (hence the p17t = place, p17l = level of building). Debugging is not a problem here, because the UPDATE queries ran successfully and have been checked for data inconsistencies. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean solely in the future when you can't figure out why something doesn't work. However if you have `p1t, p2t, p3t, p4t` etc., then you should normalize your data instead.

Comment: can you give an example of your ValueStoreTab and maybe the relation between City and ValueStoreTab? Also, column names don't have accents , column 'col' != col

Comment: ValueStoreTab looks like: row1: p1t = 1, p1l = 1, g1h = someval, g1q = someotherval; row2: p1t = 1, p1l = 2, g1h = some3val etc.; row3: p2t = 2, p2l = 1, g1h = some4val etc. p1t going up to p17t and p1l going up to p32l but varying. The relation is not specified at the moment, but other than identical combinations of p1t-p17t and p1l-p32l in both tables there are no IDs to connect.

Comment: normalize, normalize, normalize

Comment: I don't get it. You want to replace an update statement with an insert statement? You want the insert statement to actually update records, not insert them? Because you think it's faster? Well, there's `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`, but that's a different story. And it certainly is not faster. Apart from that, replacing update with insert is not possible. Was someone trying to fool you?

Comment: I have info on building type and building level for each of 17 fields for 1000s of rows, each differing. Each building + level combination is associated with different values for the building materials. I want to fill the building material fields depending on building and level for each row. Since the material fields are empty I thought to use INSERT instead of UPDATE, because it takes my computer full days to calculate all the updates.

Comment: `it takes my computer full days to calculate all the updates` <- There's something wrong with your computer. Again, an insert can not replace an update. If you have rows with `null` values in some columns either delete the rows and insert again or fix your indexes on the fields that identify the row to be updated. I'd prefer the latter.

Comment: I don't seem to get your table structure...

Comment: My computer is absolutely ok, in fact it is rather fast - it is just the sheer number of updates (16000 Queries * 17DBs * 15000 rows per DB). There are no NULL values. The table structure is (cols): building type/building level/material1/material2/etc. with type and level variable per row and the material should be inserted depending on type and level. So, my original question remains (but thanks for the help so far!): Is there an INSERT Syntax with a WHERE condition on the table to be modified??

Answer (score 0):

To give a quick answer insert with a select statement is possible

```
Insert INTO MyTable (Val1, Val2)
Select 
 SomeValue, 
 AnotherValue
From MyOtherTable
Where Date = Getdate()
```

On the other hand, you can also update many records like in the following example:

```
Update t1
Set 
 t1.Val1 = t2.SomeValue,
 t1.Val2 = t2.AnotherValue
From MyTable t1 
Inner join MyOtherTable t2 ON t1.PK = t2.FK
where t2.Date = getdate()
```

EDIT:

When i read the following query, I presume p17t and p17l are from the valuestoretab.

```
UPDATE city c 
SET 
 c.g17h = '3196504', 
 c.g17q = '2593487', 
 c.g17k = '0', 
 c.g17w = '0', 
 c.g17s = '0' 
WHERE
 p17t = 30 AND p17l = '30';
```

==> changed this into:

```
UPDATE c 
SET 
 c.g17h = '3196504', 
 c.g17q = '2593487', 
 c.g17k = '0', 
 c.g17w = '0', 
 c.g17s = '0' 
FROM City c, ValueStoreTab v
WHERE
 c.SomeCol = v.SomeCol -- Here, your relation must exist!
 AND v.p17t = 30 AND v.p17l = '30';
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not solve the problem, because any WHERE t1.col = t2.col condition results in the error "unknown column name t1.col in WHERE clause".

Comment: change "col" to actual column name from your table?